# `GM_xmlhttpRequest`の`onload`で得た変数を外に持って行くにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

`GM_xmlhttpRequest`の`onload`で得た変数を外に持って行くにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
var GetPageList = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="http://www.example.net/"]');
for (var i = 0; i < GetPageList.length; i++) {
  var GetPageLink = GetPageList[i].href;
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: GetPageLink,
    onload: function(response) {
      var responseXML = null;
      responseXML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response.responseText, "text/html");
      var GetTargetLink1 = response.responseText.replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
      var GetTargetLink2 = GetTargetLink1.replace(/^.*<a href=\"([^"]*)\">More information...<\/a>.*$/g, "$1");
    }
  });
  // ここで変数を読み込みたい
  console.log(GetTargetLink2)
}
```

Comment: SO本家の類似質問で、[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)と[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)を使う[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561572)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: ご教授頂きありがとうございます。参考にして書き直した結果無事に動かすことが出来ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄で教えてもらった英語版における類似質問の [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561572) を参考に、
[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) と [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) を使った以下のような記述にすることで解決しました。

```
var GetPageList = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="http://www.example.net/"]');
function makeGetRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: "GET",
      url: GetPageLink,
      onload: function(response) {
        resolve(response.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < GetPageList.length; i++) {
  var GetPageLink = GetPageList[i].href;
  var response = await makeGetRequest();
  var GetTargetLink1 = response.replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
  var GetTargetLink2 = GetTargetLink1.replace(/^.*<a href=\"([^"]*)\">More information...<\/a>.*$/g, "$1");
  console.log(GetTargetLink2)
}
```